# How to change the value of a specific part of a text file each time the analysis is over?

Tags: fortran

I am analyzing  by reading a text file with Fortran.
I want to overwrite the value of a specific part of a text file each time the analysis is over.
It is entered in the textile file as shown below.

```
64,0.015d-4,0.01d+6,0,
```

I want to overwrite only the real part of the value of the third column, like 0, 02, 0, 03 ... every time the main program ends.

Comment: Welcome. See [ask] and [mcve]. Do you have any code to show? What is the structure of that file? How many files does it contain, just this one or more lines?

Comment: Usually with text files it's a waste of your time and effort trying to update in place, far more straightforward to read one version of the file and write an updated version. It's much easier to test this approach to boot.  And no-one using text files gets to complain about inefficiencies in reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

You question is vague and lack of details but generally if your file has equal length records, you can open it as direct access. Otherwise, you may want to open it as a sequential one.

More details can be found from the second answer (not the accepted one) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176611/overwrite-a-file-using-fortran/38178770)