# Trouble with gfortran : the end-of-file record seems badly recorded with unformatted stream files

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I try to generate a Unix text file on my Windows computer.

Here is an example of input file "foo" (with Windows end-of-line characters). This file contains 10 lines :

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

Here is a Fortran program translating that file into a Unix file but keeping only the five first lines :

```
program test
   implicit none
   character(255) :: line(1000)
   integer :: i,n
   open(15,file = "foo.txt")
   do i=1,size(line)
      read(15,'(a)',end=10) line(i)
   enddo
   10 continue
   n=i-1
   write(*,*) n
   close(15)
   open(15,file="foo.txt",form="unformatted",access="stream")
   do i=1,5
      write(15) 'unix ',trim(line(i))
      write(15) achar(10)
   enddo
   close(15)
end program
```

But when I enter the command "type foo.txt" in a cmd window, I get :

```
unix line 1
unix line 2
unix line 3
unix line 4
unix line 5
 9
line 10
```

Notice the two unexpected extra lines at the end of the file !

Version of gfortran :

GNU Fortran (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Bug in gfortran or mistake somewhere ?

Comment: What did you expect to get?  You read in "line mode / record mode" and are writing in "stream mode" You overwrite more characters back than that are present on the lines and thus overwriting also lines you thought you didn't touch.

Comment: I expected to get only 5 lines but I get 7 lines as if the end-of-file record after the 5th line was not recorded properly

Comment: Have a look at the answer from IanH with the question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176611/overwrite-a-file-using-fortran

Comment: I read the answer of IanH but it does not seem to be related to the trouble I mention here

Comment: In case of stream mode the file is not truncated but overwriting the parts (like it does in e.g. C). Easiest probably would be to open the file without stream (i.e. sequential), write 1 record, close it and write again in stream mode (or maybe just write everything in sequential mode).

Comment: Sorry but I disagree. When I write 5 lines into a file and close this one just after, I expect only five lines in that file and, as far as I know, this does not depend on the access mode (sequential or stream).

Comment: I cannot find the exact definition in the standard but all things indicate to me a non-truncation. From the http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Stream+Input+Output is is also not 100% clear to me.

Comment: It could but this is the default normally. More precisely, the default is status='unknown' which behaves here as status='replace'

Comment: OK thanks ! When I put status='replace', then I get the expected result. Anyway, in my actual application, I do not know the right status of the file. I just want to create a new file if it does not exist or to replace the previous version. Up to now (since 1984 with the arrival of first F77 compilers) I always used, status='unknown'  in that case.

Comment: @Francois Jacq, I think you need to spend sometime with the Fortran standard.  Suppose you have a 1 MB file opened with `access=stream`.  You can write to position 100 in that file with `write(unit=fd,pos=100) x` for some unit number `fd` and variable `x`.  If you immediately close that file, what is the size of the file?

Comment: OK Steve : I certainly need to study stream access which I usually do not use...

Comment: @Francois Jacq, "since 1984 with the arrival of first F77 compiler" you have not used stream access. While access=sequential truncated the file when writing, access=stream does not do this. For stream I/O, if the file exists, you will have to truncate the file, either by first deleting or perhaps ENDFILE may help (not sure). With windows file system, it can be dangerous to delete then create the same file many times.

Comment: @johncampbell yes I have well understood now that access="Stream" and access"sequential" do not behave identically and this is the cause of my mistake.. But I think that the suggestion of High Performance Mark is accurate : (status="replace")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by High Performance Mark, here is an answer of my own question :

When opening an existing file, access="Stream" and access="sequential," do not behave identically as mentioned in an early Albert's comment  :

- a WRITE statement in sequential access automatically deletes the rest
  of the file
- a WRITE statement in stream access keeps the rest of the file intact
  (which allows to modify slightly a file without having to rewrite it
  entirely)

To come back to the sequential behavior even in a stream access, it is necessary to specify status="replace" in the OPEN statement.